# Searching multiple mysql tables for the same 2 fields in each table

Tags: linux, mysql, php

I am trying to figure out how to search mysql tables for the same 2 fields. What I have is 2 tables in the same database. Below is what I have currently:-

single search works ok

```
SELECT *  FROM `table1` WHERE `acked` != 1 AND `host_status` = 'HOSTDOWN'
```

returns results which is good and expected.

Whereas trying to combine the 2 tables searching for the same although it does not error up, but at the same does not return any results which I can kind of understand as I am using 'AND'

```
SELECT `table1`.*, `table2`.*
FROM table1, table2
WHERE (`table1`.`acked` != '1' AND `table1`.`host_status` = 'HOSTDOWN')
AND (`table2`.`acked` != '1' AND `table2`.`host_status` = 'HOSTDOWN')
```

But if I use the following using 'OR' I get results but not the expected results, I also get the acked value of 1 and 0 but with the host_status of HOSTUP

```
SELECT `table1`.*, `table2`.*
FROM table1, table2
WHERE (`table1`.`acked` != '1' AND `table1`.`host_status` = 'HOSTDOWN')
OR (`table2`.`acked` != '1' AND `table2`.`host_status` = 'HOSTDOWN')
```

any pointers?

Comment: Why do you have two tables with the same columns?

Comment: Hi, its a long story, basically its to decrease script run times to a minute. Currently I have the one script that takes 3 minutes which is too long.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer which was to use `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `acked` != 1 AND `host_status` = 'HOSTDOWN' UNION 
SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `acked` != 1 AND `host_status` = 'HOSTDOWN'
```